# Dynamically and automatically give out SSL certificates for new domains

Tags: nginx

I have a service that allows others to bring their own domains for. Currently, the system goes as follows:

1. User points their domain to our servers
2. User sends domain to us
3. We run a custom add command on the server
4. The add command then automatically setups all of our nginx config and uses certbot to get them a certificate

We would like to automate this process, so a user does not have to send us the link or enter it into some kind of field for the add command to be ran. We would also like to not spam our nginx config, and use a more efficient approach (currently we just add a server block for each domain with the certs). I would like to streamline this and compact it, but I am not super familiar with nginx right now.
Goal: Automatically register ssl for new (user brought) domains

Comment: You will not be able to build this *solely* with NGINX.  You'll need to set up a whole set of infrastructure to do this, likely via ansible or other playlists, and this is a setup process that is far too broad to give you step-by-step on how to complete here within an answer because multiple parts have to exist and be individually developed or configured and tested before you can build this, each completely different.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for the reply, are there any alternatives like caddy that would allow me to run code inside the config? Then I could potentially run some code to find which domain they are visiting on and serve the ssl cert dynamically from a database

Comment: which won't work with NGINX.  You'd need a system that is not out of the box in that case too.  Caddy might be an option but it's still beyond the scope of a single question to set up and test.  I don't have any situation in this case that doesn't utilize code I've written to set up an 'autoconfiguration' system or such.

Comment: @ThomasWard Ok, I also saw [this github repo](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#description) and was wondering if you would have any knowledge of that, as it could potentially be used to run my add command whenever a request comes in from a domain that is not known in our database. Do you think this would be possible? Or if anyone else has experience using that tool some advice would be great. As you can probably tell im new to this, so should i attempt this method or try going with what you originally suggested?

Comment: I can't help you out with the Lua module as I don't support it, and I don't know the Lua 5.1 code it requires to do things.  I don't know if it'll assist you, and I'm not sure of the best approach for *your* needs for this,.